# Month over Month Percentage Change

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to find a way to visualize or calculate a table that displays growth or percentage change positive or negative in power bi. Is there a quick way to display that on a visual? Using Excel it would be easy to cell reference for example but how would I demonstrate this on Power BI.

The data inputted raw from SQL Server is  as follows in record:

Table: Sheet1
Col: MONTH(Whole Number),CustomerID(Whole Number),CustomerName(Text),Sales Rep (Text),Sales total (decimal),Month Name(text)

Month was original extracted from SQL Server as a datepart value. I was unable to display simply the month name in Power BI, so I created a new field with the month name and its corresponding number date part.

I want to display the following:

Filter: Sales Rep

```
Months    total   %  difference MoM growth
Jan        $
Feb        $
Mar       ...
...       ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48DEz.png)

Comment: "that displays growth or percentage change positive or negative" change in growth compared to previous month?,previous year?, previous quarter ?

Comment: OP posted MoM (month over month).   This is really a small matter with actual dates and not with MMM ... It gets ugly

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things you need to do.

1. You need to have actual Dates, not names.  Your best bet is to actually create a Date table.  Microsoft has some good information on how to do this. (See [Model Data Tables on Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/model-date-tables))
2. You can then use a number of Time intelligence functions to get prior values to do the calculations.  (See [time-intelligence-functions-dax on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax).  To filter for a prior value.

```
     CALCULATE(SUM(sales[SalesAmount]),  PREVIOUSMONTH('DateTime'[DateKey])) - SUM(sales[SalesAmount])
```

For example would give you a different value against the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is a bit tricky, since Power BI primarily works with tables and doesn't have the concept of a "previous row", like Excel does.

But using DAX variables you can break down the calculation in comprehensible steps:

```
% difference MOM growth = 
VAR this_month = 
    MAX(MyTable[MONTH])
VAR this_total = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN(MyTable[total]),
        MyTable[MONTH] = this_month
    )
VAR prev_month = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(MyTable[MONTH]),
        ALL(MyTable),
        MyTable[MONTH] < this_month
    )
VAR prev_total =
    CALCULATE(
        MIN(MyTable[total]),
        ALL(MyTable),
        MyTable[MONTH] = prev_month
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(this_total - prev_total, prev_total)
```

And after formatting the resulting measure as *Percentage* you get the requested result:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You obviously have no idea how bad that looks on a mobile device using a dark scheme.

Comment: @Dale K This is "obviously" clumsy polemics.